# arrange numbers to form largest number - proof of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, proof

There is well known [algorithmic problem](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/02/leetcode-largest-number-java/), given array of numbers e.g. `[1, 20, 3, 14]` arrange numbers in such a way that they form biggest number possible, in this case `320141`.

There is plenty of solutions on SO and other sites, using the following algorithm:

```
String[] strs = new String[nums.length];
for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    strs[i] = String.valueOf(nums[i]);
}

Arrays.sort(strs, new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        String leftRight = s1+s2;
        String rightLeft = s2+s1;
        return -leftRight.compareTo(rightLeft);

    }
});

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s: strs){
    sb.append(s);
}

return sb.toString();
```

It certainly works, but I cannot find a formal proof of this algorithm. There is one answer on [quora](http://qr.ae/RgAefL), but I wouldn't call it a formal proof.

Does anyone can give me a sketch of proof or reference some book or article? How one can get on this solution from the original problem?

PS I tried to solve original problem but my solution was wrong, I couldn't get it right, and now I could not fully understand solution.

Comment: the answer on quora seems to be quite formal to me, though indeed just a sketch. what more do you want?

Comment: cobarzan I tried to follow quora proof but can't get some steps, maybe I need something more formal or with small steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding notation: I will use pipes to separate the numbers so it's
easier to see the sequence of numbers and the *resulting number* at the
same time:  3|20|14|1

Let us assume for the moment that the relation -- let's call it *R*
represented by the `<=` operator -- that is defined by the compare
function is a total order. It is determined by the expression

```
-(a+b).compareTo(b+a)
```

Intuitively it says that if we have two numbers *a* and *b* and *b|a* is
larger than *a|b*, *b* should get a higher rank than *a*, i.e. it should
occur left of *a* in the solution. If *a|b* is larger than *b|a*, it's the other way
round. If *a|b* = *b|a*, the order does not matter.

One important thing to note is that this relation not only affects two
numbers *a* and *b* considered in isolation but also tells us something
about the resulting number the two numbers are embedded in:

**If *a<=b*, then *x|a|b|y* <= *x|b|a|y***

with *x* and *y* being numbers of
arbitrary lengths. In other words: If we have a sequence of numbers
and we swap two adjacent numbers *a* and *b* with *a<=b*, the resulting
number will be greater or equal afterwards.

Example: **3|14|20|1 <= 3|20|14|1** because **14 <= 20**

We can now lead the assumption that the solution is not the one
implied by our relation *R* to a contradiction: Let's assume the
solution is some specific sequence not conforming to *R*. Since *R* is a
total order, we can rearrange the numbers to match *R* by swapping
adjacent elements until the order conforms to *R*. This reordering can
be compared to a bubble sort. However, in each swap operation that
leads us to the new order, the resulting number increases! This is
clearly a contradiction, so the original order cannot be the the
solution.

All that is left to show is that *R* is a total order, i.e. it is
transitive, antisymmetric and total. Since you asked for a sketch of
the proof, I'll omit this part. The essential part is proving
transitivity, i.e. that

*a <= b* and *b <= c* implies *a <= c*.

Comment: Thank you, simple and easy to understand proof, I wanted exactly something like that!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch of the algorithm. For your given list:

```
[1, 20, 3, 14]
```

think about how you would find the largest concatenated number.

For the most significant digit, pick the number with the largest initial digit. (In the example, pick the 3 and then the 20. Thus the answer starts with 320.)

The remaining numbers, 1 and 14, start with the same initial digit (namely 1). Which to pick next? This is where the heart of the algorithm, the `compare` function, comes into play. It will build the numbers and compare which one is lexically larger, that is, 114 versus 141. The negative sign on the `return` statement will make sure that the bigger number goes first. So the answer would be 320141.

(The algorithm doesn't actually compare the initial digits, but rather, sorts the strings from lexically largest to smallest.)

Comment: rajah9 I asked for _proof_ of algorithm, not explanation how it works

Comment: Sorry, I was responding to your "could not fully understand solution."